# Dynamically loading form with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, dynamic

I'm learning web design and have run into a difficulty that I can't figure out by myself.
I want to dynamically load a form into a  using jQuery. My code looks like this:

From within the main file:

```
$('#left_colum').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
   $('#column_left').load(create_album.php);
});
```

create_album.php -> it contains the actual form, as well as the php script that handles it on POST. It's very basic. If I load up my_form.php by its own, it works fine. If I dynamically load it as above; the HTML works but the POST php script doesn't execute.

There is also another interesting behavior; if I click the submit button on the dynamically loaded form, it all disappears (unlike the "properly" loaded one).

I've gone through a lot of posts and tutorials, and I haven't been able to find a solution other than using iframes. It seems that people generally don't dynamically load anything other than basic HTML that doesn't have to talk back to the server. I'm new to this : P

Is there a fix or another way of doing it? Thanks!

Edit:

albums.php:

```
<?php
include 'init.php';

if(!logged_in()) {
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
}

?>

<h3>Albums</h3>
<?php
/*Output albums*/
$albums = get_albums();
if(empty($albums)) {
    echo("You don't have any albums");
} else {
    /*Changed: uploading images is now part of the albums sections*/
    foreach($albums as $album) {
        echo '<p><a class="album_view" id="'.$album['id'].'" href="">', $album['name'], '</a> (', $album['count'], ' images)<br/>Description: ', $album['description'], '...<br/><a class="album_edit" id="'.$album['id'].'" href="">Edit</a> / <a href="delete_album.php?album_id=', $album['id'], '">Delete</a> / <a class="upload_image" id="'.$album['id'].'" href="">Upload</a></p>';
    }
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        /*Creating albums*/
        $('#create_album').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#column_left').load(album.php);
        });
    });
```

create_album.php:

```
<h3>Create Album</h3>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["album_name"], $_POST["album_description"])) {

    echo 'got here';
    $album_name = $_POST["album_name"];
    $album_description = $_POST["album_description"];

    $errors = array();
    if(empty($album_name) || empty($album_description)) {
        $errors[] = "Album name and description required";
    } else {
        if(strlen($album_name) > 55 || strlen($album_description) > 255) {
            $errors[] = "Name/description too long";
        }
    }

    if(!empty($errors)) {
        foreach($errors as $error) {
            echo $error, "<br/>";
        }
    } else {
        echo 'got here, too';
        //create_album($album_name, $album_description);
        //header("Location: albums.php");
    }
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <p>Name:<br/><input type="text" name="album_name" maxlength="55"/></p>
    <p>Description:</br><textarea name="album_description" rows="6" cols="35" maxlength="255"></textarea></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Create"/></p>
</form>
```

Comment: dynamically load a form into a _____ ?

Comment: can you post a bit of markup you are working with

Comment: JQuery.load just loads the file and fills the selector. It doesn't execute PHP. You need to use a different mechanism.

Comment: Ok, I've uploaded the source. I've cut out a lot of it to minimize the wall-of-textedness

Answer (score 0):

I think that's:

```
$('#column_left').load('my_form.php');
```

right?

Anyways:

- Is the form showing up correctly?
- Try having a look at the generated source, by using firebug, in order to see if the loading was successful
- Make sure that "my_form.php" returned html isn't the whole `<html>` but just `<form>` and its content
- What's the form `action`? Is it an absolute path or not? If it is relative, it may point to different locations when called from the ajax-loading page or from `my_form.php`
- Are you submitting the form vja ajax, or "the standard way"?
- What does exactly happen when you click on form submit? Where do you get redirected?

Comment: The form shows up correctly, and it's only the <frame> object that is being loaded (no other HTML such as <body>, <head>, etc...) The form action is "". Submit doesn't redirect, it just clears the entire frame (it disappears). Submitting via POST (ajax, I think)

Comment: `<frame>`? Why are you loading frames via ajax? Plus, if the action is "", the browser submits the POST to the same path of the page displaying the form, not to `my_form.php`, as it does when submitting the form from `my_form.php`...

Answer (score 0):

because your form action would be to a different page so every time you click submit button it redirect you to that page , you can try using iframe it will work that way or if you want to use jquery only than paste some of your code so that we can understand what's actually happening... though iframe is the best solution for you as if now

Comment: Ok thanks, I've pasted the code. I want to avoid iframes, but I will if there's not other reasonable way. The action is ""; it's a "post" method.

Answer (score 0):

With your code, you load only the html part of you form. So when user push submit button, your fields had sended to original page and not to "my_form.php", where I suppose you manage POST datas.
The easiest solution is to use IFRAME to load you form code.

Answer (score 0):

Your form action is missing try this, i have tried and working on my end

album.php

```
<h3>Create Album</h3>

 <?php
if(isset($_POST["album_name"], $_POST["album_description"])) {

echo 'got here';
$album_name = $_POST["album_name"];
$album_description = $_POST["album_description"];

$errors = array();
if(empty($album_name) || empty($album_description)) {
    $errors[] = "Album name and description required";
} else {
    if(strlen($album_name) > 55 || strlen($album_description) > 255) {
        $errors[] = "Name/description too long";
    }
}

if(!empty($errors)) {
    foreach($errors as $error) {
        echo $error, "<br/>";
    }
} else {
    echo 'got here, too';
    //create_album($album_name, $album_description);
    //header("Location: albums.php");
}
     }
        ?>

     <form action="album.php" method="post">
<p>Name:<br/><input type="text" name="album_name" maxlength="55"/></p>
<p>Description:</br><textarea name="album_description" rows="6" cols="35 "maxlength="255"></textarea></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Create"/></p>
```

yourmainfile.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
      <html lang="en">  
       <head>  
<meta charset="utf-8">  
<title>Untitled</title>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $('#create_album').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#column_left').load('album.php');

    });

    });
</script>
      </head> 
        <body>
<div id="mainWrapper">
    <div id="column_left"></div><!-- end column left -->

    <a href="#" id="create_album"> Create New Album </a>

</div><!--end mainWrapper-->
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: That works : D When I change the action parameter like you describe, POST gets executed at that location with the variables - can just move the php script into it's own file. Thanks so much!